# How to abort vue.js method post if any required fields are null

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

On click at button "Salvar" I need to verify if any required fields are null and if one of those are null, I need to abort vue.js method post before it goes to the action in controller.

Is there anyone that can help me out?

Here is the code:

Thanks!

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    data: {
        endereco: "",
        cidade: "",
        estado: "",
        cep: "",
    },
    methods: {
        postResults: function () {
            this.$http.post('/Controller/Action/', {
                Endereco: this.endereco,
                Cidade: this.cidade,
                Estado: this.estado,
                CEP: this.cep,
                SEND: false
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.data.worked);
                if (response.data.worked) {
                    console.log("DADOS ADICIONADOS!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label" for="endereco">
                                Endereço
                            </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco" v-model="endereco" required>
  <span class="material-input"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label" for="cidade">
                                Cidade
                            </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade" v-model="cidade" required>
  <span class="material-input"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label" for="estado">
                                Estado
                            </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estado" v-model="estado" required>
  <span class="material-input"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label" for="cep">
                                CEP
                            </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" v-model="cep" required>
  <span class="material-input"></span>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 80%;" v-on:click="postResults" type="submit">Salvar</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you should wrap this in a form:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="postResults">
```

Then remove the click handler from the button.

Next, create a new method, we'll call it `validatesFields`. Make it return a promise that either resolves or rejects based on validity:

```
validatesFields: function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (this.field.valid && this.other_field.valid&&) {
      return resolve()
    } else {
      return reject()
    }   
  })
}
```

Finally, observe this promise in your `postResults` function:

```
postResults: function () {
   this.validatesFields()
     .then(function(){
       this.$http.post('/Controller/Action/', {
          Endereco: this.endereco,
          Cidade: this.cidade,
          Estado: this.estado,
          CEP: this.cep,
          SEND: false
       }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          console.log(response.data.worked);
          if (response.data.worked) {
            console.log("DADOS ADICIONADOS!");
          }
        });
     }).error(function(){
       // field validation failed, do something here
     })

    }
```

Comment: I've tried it but i had an error at form tag: The name 'submit' does not exist in the current context.
`<form @submit.prevent="postResults">`

Comment: Oh, it's asp.net, Use the bindings: `v-on:submit.prevent="postResults"`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!
I just remove **.error(function(){
       // field validation failed, do something here
     })**
And here **if (this.field.valid && this.other_field.valid&&)** I removed .valid.